# Should I use use multiply activities or something else? [Android]

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm new in Android Studio and I'm making a project. It's an app to learn new words and I want to make that, for example it'll be only 20 words (and in this app user will have to swipe the screen to new word). And it must be 20 other activities? Because I think it could be only one activity, but multiplied 20 times with other TextView. But how to do it?

I remind you that I'm new in Android development :D

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: use `SharedPreferences` to save data and when swipe just populate next row of data

Comment: Three activities, first is a "menu", in this activity is showing a button with text "Lesson 1", when I press this button, it's moving to activity 2 - there is two TextViews, first one upper is word in my native language, and second one in down is word in English language. And in this second activity is button, that move me to third activity and there is the same like in activity 2, but other word

Comment: You can try fragment for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Fragments` and `ViewPager`, here tutorial from official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: But for example if I want to have 500 words, I have to do 500 Fragments?

Comment: @rradzzio No, you should create one fragment and pass your word as variable through `newInstance(String word)` (you can search about newInstance on the Internet).

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial) simple demo for using ViewPager with dynamic values.